# How to display a "never" date in an Excel pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table, date-formatting

I'll start by saying that I understand that Excel dates are really just numbers that are formatted in a nice way.

I have a table with about 2000 rows, half of which have dates. The dates are calculated using a `VLOOKUP` from another table in another sheet. The ones that don't have dates have the `#N/A` error. The entire date field is formatted as a date and I *can* sort the field as a date.

The problem occurs when I create a pivot table using my table. The pivot table does not recognize the `#N/A` errors as errors and instead converts the whole field to text. I can no longer sort or filter as a date.

The ones without dates don't necessarily have to be `#N/A`. They could be anything other than 0 or "" because those get converted to 01/00/1900. The ones without dates have to be empty or filled with something that does not interfere with the date formatting.

Any suggestions on what that may be?

Comment: You can use `IFERROR` like this: `IFERROR(Vlookup(...),0)`

Comment: If I do that, the 0 automatically gets converted to 01/00/1900.
That's just how excel formats zeros in its date fields.

Comment: @pnuts, that partially solves my problem! I set the source as `[=0]"NONE";dd/mm/yyyy` and in the PT it shows up as `NONE`.
The issue, and I'm being picky at this point, is that when sorting I'd like to have the `NONE` dates after the other dates instead of before them all. They are still 01/00/1900 after all.

Comment: I believe pivot tables support custom sorting. I suggest trying it out.

Comment: if you want the `NONE`s to show up "later" than valid dates use a big number instead of 0 for their replacement.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor any insight as to what the largest date I can enter into excel is?
Edit: Nevermind, `December 31, 9999`

Comment: @pnuts That's true but then the default could be changed back to 0 if desired.  I don't think there's a way to specify that some rows should always be at the top regardless of any applied sorting (other than not including them in the sort itself).  If there's a better way to achieve what OP wants with that regard I don't know it.

Comment: @pnuts different strokes for different folks.

Comment: It all worked out quite nicely actually and I feel as if my problem is completely solved. Thank you pnuts and Dean :)

Comment: You can also grab a pivot table row with your mouse and drag it to where you would like it to be. If I remember right, this will act as a custom sort and keep that item in that position. Just tested this, and any new dates will be added after the **none** or **0** or whatever you are using. So may not be the best option after all.

Answer (score 0):

I think kbsou is close to the solution but you should use ISNA not IFERROR on your VLOOKUP.

I got this to work just fine
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1,A:A,1))," ",VLOOKUP(B1,A:A,1))

Copy in your VLOOKUP as is and it should work for you.

Edit: Missed comments further down, looks like you found your solution.